# tensorflowlite.so building for android failed, how to fix error "name 'closure_proto_library' is not defined"

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-ndk, bazel, tensorflow-lite

tensorflow version r1.9
bazel 0.11.1
ndk r14
api-level 23

command :

```
bazel build //tensorflow/contrib/lite:libtensorflowLite.so --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool --cpu=arm64-v8a --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain --cxxopt="-std=c++11"
```

error:

````
ERROR: /home/user/mypro/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:148:1: file '@io_bazel_rules_closure//closure:defs.bzl' does not contain symbol 'closure_proto_library' (did you mean 'closure_js_proto_library'?)
ERROR: /home/user/mypro/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:153:1: file '@io_bazel_rules_closure//closure:defs.bzl' does not contain symbol 'closure_proto_library' (did you mean 'closure_js_proto_library'?)
ERROR: /home/user/mypro/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:271:1: name 'closure_proto_library' is not defined
ERROR: /home/user/mypro/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:290:1: Target '//tensorflow/core:platform/platform.h' contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by '//tensorflow/core:lib_platform'
ERROR: /home/user/mypro/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/lite/BUILD:95:1: Target '//tensorflow/core:lib_platform' contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by '//tensorflow/contrib/lite:string'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/contrib/lite:libtensorflowLite.so' failed; build aborted: Loading failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 12.701s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (24 packages loaded)```
````

Comment: that's a really old Bazel version. have you tried using something newer, like 0.22?

Comment: I have tried 0.22,0.21, howerever  build failed  ,could you tell me which version that you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Likely there is version mismatch between the bazel tool and the version of tensorflow. You can check the recommended bazel tool in the tensorflow version you should use from here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source

In your case, the recommended build tool is Bazel 0.11.0, and you use version Bazel 0.11.1 (although it is minor version difference).